# pdf with form and send mail button that does not work in gnome

Tags: pdf, xml, interactive

I have this pdf form to be filled anytime I need an additional and temporary worker in my restaurant (for example, an additional waiter).  The PDF has been created by the government working agency and it must be filled with the emplyer's data and the worker's data (mainly, social security number and dates he will be working).
At the end, this pdf has a button that takes all the info of the pdf, creates an xml file and send it to a specific email address.

The thing is: on windows this works flawlessly, while in ubuntu I can't get the generate xml and send mail button work. Is there something you can suggest me to make this thing work?

The PDF form can be found and downloaded [here](https://www.cliclavoro.gov.it/Aziende/Adempimenti/Documents/UNI_Intermittenti_giugno2015.pdf)

Some useful info: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with gnome and evince to read pdf files

Thank you in advance

Comment: Evince is a very featureless viewer. https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince/ComparingEvinceAcroread

Comment: @IporSircer so which pdf reader do you suggest me? Once upon a time I had used KDE and I liked all the features of Okular but I don't want to install half of KDE deps to have Okular...

Comment: Ask your government what they suggest. Adobe reader is available for Linux, but it isn't free. https://pdf.wondershare.com/pdf-software-comparison/adobe-reader-for-linux.html